# How to enable netbeans intellisense/autocomplete for protractor?

Tags: netbeans, protractor, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I'm creating html5 project using netbeans IDE, and set-up all related testing configuration for protractor.

when i create new test file (.js), and type something like `element` or `element(by.)`, netbeans tooltips "No Sugestion"

how to enable netbeans intelisense/autocomplete for protractor?
according to netbeans wiki, protractor supported since 8.1 http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB81#Protractor

I use netbeans 8.2

Comment: seems netbeans not support protractor intelisense

Answer (score 1):

Instead of netbeans, you can use webstorm, which have rich support for .js, .ts and protractor itself...